# CanExecute is checked only when accessing Page, and not on property changed

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

This is my first question on StackOverflow!

Im using WinUI with .NET Community Toolkit MVVM
The problem is that CanExecute on button fires only when accessing Page. I want it to fire on every keystroke in the TextBox. Am i missing something?

View:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt1" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.NrTelefonu, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="300" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20 0 0 0" />

<Button Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SendSmsCommand}" Style="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20 20 0 0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Text="Wyślij SMS" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE8F3;" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 0 0" FontSize="25"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

View Model:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string nrTelefonu;

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSendSms))] 
    private void SendSms()
    {
       //sends SMS
    }

    private bool CanSendSms()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NrTelefonu))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Im expecting to enable this button if textblock isn't empty. I would like to validate it one every keystroke. However it doesnt even work on losing focus when textbox is filled. I dont know what to do at this point. Im not extremely advanced in MVVM.

Answer (score 2):

modifying property to this fixed my problem:

```
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SendSmsCommand))]
private string nrTelefonu;
```

Comment: Nice work. You can accept your answer.